# Running Shell Script via IDE (inteliJ) and receiving: Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions

Tags: java, windows, shell, sh

Running Shell Script via IDE (inteliJ) and receiving: Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions, any ideas why?

My code:

```
public class TestScript {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] cmd = { "bash", "-c", "ExecutorTest.sh" };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:

https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

Comment: Do you have Windows Susbsystem for Linux installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to run bash and bash-scripts on a Windows box, Windows Subsystem for Linux needs to be installed. You might want to try installing it. Or, if you transform the bash script into Windows batch script, you can run it by starting `cmd`.